# Quartz JobDataMap

Tags: java, serialization, version-control, quartz-scheduler

The quartz site has a tip about `JobDataMap`(http://quartz-scheduler.org/generated/2.2.1/html/qs-all/#page/Quartz_Scheduler_Documentation_Set%2Fco-bp_jobdatamap_tips.html%23) mentioned:

> Only store primitive data types (including Strings) in JobDataMap to
>   avoid data serialization issues short and long-term.

Please let me know if my assumptions are correct:

1. Above is just a **guide line**. I can store and retrieve non primitive object as an `job data`. The Scheduler will **not fail**.
2. If I store a non primitive data I may face design issues. The issue will happen as soon as I change the serialized object properties. After changing the version of the object which is in my code will be different from the one which is stored in quartz db.
3. If I find a proper version control mechanism of serialize and desalinizing objects, then I can use Quartz Scheduler to store objects as `JobDataMap` (Some guidlines are mentioned in http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071731/core-java/ensure-proper-version-control-for-serialized-objects.html?page=1 or http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-5things1/index.html)

---

In my project the jobs needs LOTS OF COMPLEX datamap to run, so passing all these data as primitive data will be a big headache.

Answer (score 2):

According to my experience, it's not essential to use primitive types, it is just a recommendation. But it is too useful and safe to do so, I recommend if you can, just utilize primitive types, for example you can store your desired data in a table of a database and put the `id` of that record to `JobDataMap`.

Comment: This should be commen

Comment: sorry, I think by that time I didn't have the privilege of leaving comment! or there was other issue maybe.

Comment: Another option is to decompose the object into a Dictionary/Hashtable then rebuild it when you need to read it.